# three menu icons appear instead of one. (two unwritten divs of menu icons appear)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

If you go to https://hcbcke.netlify.app/  and view the site in smart phone view mode on the browser **you will notice that three menu icons appear** instead of one. If you **inspect the element of the menu icons** you will see that three div's appear that look like this
`<div class="responsive-menu-icon"></div>`

When I saw this I was shocked because as you see my HTML code I only wrote one div that looks like that.

**You can download all the website source code** at https://github.com/kimanicharles911/hope_city_bible_church .

The source code **does not require any installation** just run index.html on your website. The div is in line 782 of index.html

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="nav-primary" aria-label="Main">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="responsive-menu-icon"></div>
    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu genesis-nav-menu menu-primary responsive-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-116" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-103 current_page_item menu-item-116">
        <a href="#" aria-current="page"><span>Home</span></a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-115" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-115">
        <a href="#"><span>About</span></a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-112" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-112">
        <a href="#"><span>Music</span></a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-111" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-111">
        <a href="#"><span>Training</span></a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-9230" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-9230">
        <a href="#"><span>Blog</span></a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-3048" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom social-icon facebook menu-item-3048">
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.facebook.com/hcbcke/">
          <span>
                      <i class="icon-2x icon-facebook"></i>
                      <span class="fa-hidden">Facebook</span>
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-3049" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom social-icon twitter menu-item-3049">
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="#">
          <span>
                      <i class="icon-2x icon-twitter"></i>
                      <span class="fa-hidden">Twitter</span>
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-3050" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom social-icon youtube menu-item-3050">
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="#">
          <span>
                      <i class="icon-2x icon-youtube"></i>
                      <span class="fa-hidden">YouTube</span>
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-6279" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom social-icon instagram menu-item-6279">
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="#">
          <span>
                      <i class="icon-2x icon-instagram"></i>
                      <span class="fa-hidden">Instagram</span>
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-8331" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-8331">
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="#">
          <span>
                      <i class="fab fa-spotify icon-2x"></i>
                    </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-8332" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-8332">
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="#">
          <span>
                      <i class="fab fa-apple icon-2x"></i>
                    </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-5105" class="bop-nav-search menu-item menu-item-type-search menu-item-object- menu-item-5105">
        <form class="bop-nav-search menu-item menu-item-type-search menu-item-object- menu-item-5105" role="search" method="get" action="#">
          <label>
                      <span class="screen-reader-text">Search</span>
                      <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder value name="s" title>
                    </label>
          <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search">
        </form>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I tried to make a [mcve]

Comment: global.js remove line 15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the buttons get added via javascript, in your case it's from [this script](https://sovereigngracemusic.org/wp-content/themes/altitude-pro/js/global.js?ver=1.0.0).

The reason it gets added twice is because you load **EVERY** script twice.

Code snippet is directly from your source code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://sovereigngracemusic.org/wp-content/themes/altitude-pro/js/global.js?ver=1.0.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/global.js"></script>
```

To fix this issue load every script only once and remove the `<div class="responsive-menu-icon"></div>` from your html since it gets added automatically on page load.